# Send SMS using Journey Builder Triggered by Salesforce Event

Tags: journeybuilder, mobileconnect

I am trying to configure a journey triggered by a Salesforce Custom Object which then sends an SMS message to the contact associated with the object.  I'm not exactly sure which contact fields I should include in the event data to allow the SMS message to be sent? Are there pre-requsite steps like adding all the Contact data to a mobile connect list, and somehow opting in the contact key?

Answer (score 1):

Yes the Contact needs to be opted in to receive the SMS. One way to check:

Navigate to MobileStudio>>MobileConnect (MobileConnect>>Overview) there is a "Contacts" table in the upper right hand corner displaying "Mobile Opt-Ins" Total. Click on "Manage" and have a look there to make sure the contact is in that Channel and has a mobile number with the correct international code.

You can import into that list to manually optin the contact/s.

Answer (score 0):

I came across the same situation and I followed these steps:

1. In event data, select Contact:First Name, Contact:Mobile Phone and you will be able to receive the SMS.

Howevere, when you create the message in Mobile Connect, you have to follow these steps before selecting the message in JB.

- Make sure you have a keyword selected for the message.
- In JB, when the message is selected and you proceed to step 2, select "subscribe all contacts to a keyword" and choose the created keyword.
- Check "Opt-In" and click Next.

With the above steps, you should be able to receive the SMS.